where is the tomcat dump file for -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError?
where is the tomcat dump file for  -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError?
-XX:HeapDumpPath is not specified.
the tomcat9 is started using systemctl.
